# What's the simplest way to use a vertex array in OpenGL (for 2d graphics)? Is it even necessary?

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

I've been using OpenGL in a pretty basic way to draw textured quads for various 2D graphics projects. I've been using `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` to draw the two triangles that make up each textured quad, but I know that it's also possible to draw shapes with a vertex array.

However, the tutorials I've found seemed geared towards 3d graphics and involve loading shaders and such. All I need to do (for now at least) is draw textured quads, so this seems like overkill.

First of all, how much advantage is there to using vertex arrays in 2d? If there is advantage, what is the simplest way to use it?

Answer (score 0):

> how much advantage is there to using vertex arrays in 2d?

The advantage is huge in terms of performance. Vertex arrays greatly reduce the amount of API calls. This increases your rendering performance.

A disadvantage is that it is more complicated overall.

> If there is advantage, what is the simplest way to use it?

Vertex arrays can be used for many different forms of rendering. For basic straight up rendering it is usually in the following structure:

```
//initializing
glGenBuffer
glBindBuffer
glBufferData

//Rendering
glBindBuffer
glVertexAttribPointer
glDrawArrays
```

There are lots of tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

The `glBegin()`/`glEnd()` approach is typically referred to as "immediate mode". Vertex arrays can be massively more efficient than immediate mode, particularly when they are stored in buffers (VBO = Vertex Buffer Object). This may not be a big deal as long as your drawing involves very few vertices, but becomes critical when you're dealing with geometry with a large number of vertices.

The main reasons why arrays are more efficient than immediate mode are:

- They require a lot fewer OpenGL API calls, since you specify entire arrays with a single call, instead of making a call for each vertex. This adds up when you have millions of vertices.
- The data can be specified once, and then reused in each frame as long as it does not change. In combination with VBOs, the vertex data can also be stored in memory that the GPU can access very efficiently.

There is another aspect. Immediate mode is not available anymore in most OpenGL versions:

- It was never available in OpenGL ES, which is used on mobile devices.
- It has been marked as deprecated in desktop OpenGL starting in version 3.0, which was released in 2008.
- It is not available in the core profile, which was introduces with version 3.2.

The only way to still use immediate mode is with old OpenGL versions, or by using the compatibility profile that retains the deprecated features. The same is true for plain vertex arrays, only arrays in VBOs are supported in these newer versions.

The fixed function pipeline is equally deprecated, so writing your own shaders is required in all these newer OpenGL versions.

Some of this certainly adds complexity when starting out. It does require more code to get simple examples up and running. But once you crossed the initial hurdle, you gain a lot of flexibility, and much of the functionality actually becomes easier to use and understand.

An alternative is to use a higher level toolkit. There are plenty of options for graphics toolkits and game engines.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i'm wondering, though, do i still have to deal with loading shaders etc. even though i'm not really using them?

Comment: Yes, with the core profile and with OpenGL ES, you always have to load a shader. There is no fixed function rendering anymore. In fact, GPUs have been operating mostly in programmable mode for 10-15 years. If you use the fixed function pipeline, the driver generates a shader for you in that case.